# Glyph uploaded from freetype to opengl is stretched

Tags: c, opengl, rust, freetype

I am attempting to render some text in freetype using subpixel rendering. When I render large sizes of text the results look adequate, with only some color fringes, which I think are expected. As I decrease the size however, the results become progressively more blurry as well as becoming slightly stretched. These are the results of drawing "Hello" as pixel sizes 13, 18, and 100.

[image: Three examples of the problem]
As you can see, pixel size 100 is fairly legible, aside from slight blurriness and color fringes. Pixel size 18 is still readable, though ugly. Pixel size 13 however is so distorted that only someone who knew it was supposed to be a word could recognize it.

This is how I get my bitmaps from freetype:

```
let bitmap_glyph = glyph.to_bitmap(freetype::render_mode::RenderMode::Lcd, None).unwrap();
let bitmap = bitmap_glyph.bitmap();
let texture = Texture::from_freetype_bitmap(bitmap);
```

This is the code which I currently use to generate my textures:

```
pub fn from_freetype_bitmap(bitmap: freetype::Bitmap) -> Texture {
    let width = bitmap.width();
    let height = bitmap.rows();

    let mut texture = 0;
    unsafe {
        gl::GenTextures(1, &mut texture);
        assert!(texture != 0);
        gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);
        gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl::LINEAR as i32);
        gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl::CLAMP_TO_EDGE as i32);
        gl::TexParameteri(gl::TEXTURE_2D, gl::TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl::CLAMP_TO_EDGE as i32);
        gl::PixelStorei(gl::UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        let data = bitmap.buffer();
        let pitch = bitmap.pitch();
        let dataWidth = width / 3;

        let mut finalData = Vec::<u8>::new();
        for i in 0..height {
            for j in 0..dataWidth {
                finalData.push(data[(i * pitch + (j * 3) + 0) as usize]);
                finalData.push(data[(i * pitch + (j * 3) + 1) as usize]);
                finalData.push(data[(i * pitch + (j * 3) + 2) as usize]);
                finalData.push(0xff);
            }
        }

        gl::TexImage2D(
            gl::TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            gl::RGBA as GLint,
            dataWidth, height,
            0, 
            gl::RGBA,
            gl::UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            mem::transmute(finalData.as_ptr())
        );
    }

    let mut mesh = Mesh::new();

    mesh.add_vertex(0.0, 0.0); mesh.add_vertex(0.0, 0.0);
    mesh.add_vertex(width as f32, 0.0); mesh.add_vertex(1.0, 0.0);
    mesh.add_vertex(width as f32, height as f32); mesh.add_vertex(1.0, 1.0);
    mesh.add_vertex(0.0, height as f32); mesh.add_vertex(0.0, 1.0);

    return Texture {
        mesh: mesh, 
        texture: texture
    }
}
```

These textures are then rendered using an orthographic matrix with the origin in the top left and scaled to the window's dimensions. Thus I believe there should be no up- or down-sampling occurring when rendering. These are the shaders I am using currently:

```
// VS
#version 120
uniform vec3 tint;
uniform mat3 matrix;

attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 texCoords;

varying vec2 texFrag;

void main() {
    texFrag = texCoords;
    gl_Position = vec4(matrix * vec3(position, 1.0), 1.0);
}

// FS
#version 120

uniform vec3 tint;
uniform mat3 matrix;
uniform sampler2D texSample;

varying vec2 texFrag;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture(texSample, texFrag);
    if(color.rgb == vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) {
        color.a = 0.0;
    }
    gl_FragColor = color * vec4(tint, 1.0);
}
```

I believe my problem probably has something to do with the way I am converting the textures to RGBA. If I use the bitmap without doing this conversion (aka using RGB without the `finalData` buffer in between) the result is that the data is aligned wrongly. Changing the unpack alignment does not fix that particular bug. This makes using the data straight from freetype unworkable.

If it is relevant, the language I am using is rust, and the libraries are [gl-rs](https://github.com/bjz/gl-rs) and [freetype-rs](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/freetype-rs). I am on windows, and the freetype I am using was compiled with subpixel rendering enabled. How would I go about fixing this bug, and are there any others I should be aware of that might crop up as I continue to try to get this to work?

Comment: Subpixel rendering works *only* and *exclusively* at the (sub)pixel level. I guess you are just drawing your textures too large -- each pixel in it must equal exactly one pixel on your screen. The "100-pixel" sample shows why: the color fringes are larger than a single pixel. The same goes for the smaller sizes.

Comment: The dimensions reported by freetype are the same ones that the texture has when drawn to the screen. An increase by one in mesh width should correspond to one pixel on screen. Should I be using meshes a third of the width reported by freetype? When I try that things end up too narrow although the colors are better. Could I be doing something wrong in the way I sample the textures?